# Universal path to a file

Tags: java, file-io

How can i get universal path to a file ? so that when you transfer a application to another computer it will work correctly.

```
File fireFoxWindowsFile = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\User\\IdeaProjects\\QAsetup\\src\\main\\java\\com\\yukon\\qasetup\\xmlService\\FirefoxPortable\\FirefoxPortable.exe");
```

Expected result:

```
 File fireFoxWindowsFile = new File("FirefoxPortable\FirefoxPortabl.exe")
```

Comment: try using `classpath`. If not, `projectName/directoryName/file.txt`

Comment: Also, as long as we're dealing with 'universal' things: using forward slashes from Java works fine on Windows. This saves you the escaping and makes it platform independent ;)

Comment: Can you clarify what you want here? Do you just want to remove OS incompatibilities (path separators and so on), or are you after something else?

Comment: I just want to make the path is not attached to a specific computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path of a resource is completely dependent on the OS and kind of application that you are developing.

For stand alone applications, we can use a system property to get the separator instead of hardcoding it.

```
System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

Even then, these are relative paths which needs explicit mentioning of the drive or root and so on. AFAIK there is no concept of Universal path for files in different OS.

Answer (score 0):

Especially for the case mentioned, but also other cases, use standard java [Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29)

```
URI uri = ...;
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop.browse(uri);
}
```

I just read your question more careful (=scrolled to the right), and it could mean you want your own kind of distribution of files, or executing subdirectory executables inside a project.

You could create a maven or ant target in your IDE, using project directory variables.